# User friendly settings page in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, settings, sonata-admin

I wonder how it's possible to `implement a user friendly settings page in symfony (sonata admin)` ...

Imagine i have `settings called "Email address for error mails" and "Email address for success mails" ...` 
I can save this configuration into the `parameters.yml`, but that can not be rewritten by the user in the frontend.

On the other hand, if the `application is newly created and the settings will be saved` into the `database (as Entity "Setting") instead`

> How the user frontend can know, what settings are available to set
>   and to render?

An email address should not have a default setting in my opinion, so make a file with default values is no option.

Does anybody know a good and simple approach?

Comment: I suggest you to download for example a joomla cms, and see how it's done...

Comment: Maybe you will like my settingsBundle: https://github.com/Fbeen/SettingsBundle If you have any questions let me know :-)

Comment: By the way: Every setting has a default value if it can be NULL. Your application has to deliver warnings or errors to the frontend user that the setting is not made yet.